# onClick function requires two clicks to update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to create an app that has favoriting functionality.
The functionality actually works but only after the second click.

*Edit for additional information:* On the first click, the app tries to send information to my database but it's incomplete. It's only sending my initial values. On the second click, it finally appends the additional required values and gets saved to the database.

I'm pretty new to hooks so please feel free to comment on any improvement my code can use.
Here is my React component that is handling everything.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const ItemInfo = (props) => {

  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [ favorite, setFavorite ] = useState({favoritable_type: 'Item', favoritor_type: 'User' })

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/items/${props.match.params.id}`)
    .then((response)=>{
      if(response.status === 200){
          return(response.json())
        }
      })
      .then((item) => {
        setItem(item);
      })
  }, []);

  const createFavorite = (data) => {
    fetch(`/favorites`, {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': props.token
      },
      method: 'POST'
    })
    .then((resp) => {
      if (resp.ok) {
        setFavorite({})
        alert('This items has been favorited!')
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  }

  const handleFavorite = () => {
    const value = { favoritor_id: props.current_user.id, favoritable_id: item.id }
    setFavorite(favorite => ({...favorite, value}));
    createFavorite(favorite)
  }
```

If I'm being completely honest, I'm not exactly sure what this is doing.
I came across an answer that had something similar and it seems to fix the issue in the console but not in the actual POST attempt.

```
  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(favorite)
  },[favorite])
```

All this seems to work fine.

```
  if (item === null) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  } 

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <Button onClick={ handleFavorite } >Favorite</Button>
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
      <p>{item.body}</p>
      <p>{item.user_id}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ItemInfo;
```

I've tried separating some of the functionality into different components, recreating it using a class component and have not been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since hook values are constants, they don't change immediately with the setHookName, they change on the next render. You can get somewhat around this by injecting code into the setHookName function like this:

```js
const handleFavorite = () => {
  setFavorite(oldFavorite => {
    const value = { favoritor_id: props.current_user.id, favoritable_id: item.id };
    const newFavorite = {...oldFavorite, ...value};
    createFavorite(newFavorite);
    return newFavorite;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried your suggestion but had the same result. I think I might not have explained it clearly though. The problem I'm having is that my onClick triggers my createFavorite(POST) function, as it should, but the state that is getting sent to the backend is only my initial value. The additional values don't get added until the second click, which then gets sent and saved in the database.

Comment: This is a strange outcome, since `newFavorite` itself isn't a hook and is defined by the value of the `oldFavorite` combined with `value`, and `newFavorite` is directly inputted to `createFavorite()`, and `oldFavorite` becomes `newFavorite` at the end. I have modified this answer slightly, so try it. Let me know the outcome, and be sure to copy this and replace the entire old `handleFavorite = () => {...}` section

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. When you say `I did have to make an adjustment to it` do you mean that you have to make an adjustment to my most recent code to get it to work, or that the most recent code works and the "adjustment" you made was copying it?

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I did have to make an adjustment to it.
`const handleFavorite = () => {
    setFavorite(oldFavorite => {
      const newFavorite = {...oldFavorite, favoritor_id: props.current_user.id, favoritable_id: item.id};
      createFavorite(newFavorite);
    });
  }`
For some reason, the constant of value was being inserted as an additional object instead of the values combing to form one object so I just added the values in. Also, it worked with/without the ```return newFavorite```.Can you explain that if you can? I was wondering what that was doing. Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: @Plankartes7 The reason that constant wasn't working the way you wanted it to was because, while you did spread the `oldFavorite`, you didn't spread the `value` variable too. I noticed this, but I was thinking that you didn't spread it since i though that you wanted `value` to be an attribute of the favorite instead of the values inside of value to be attributes of the favorite. See my new edit, and please click the checkmark by the upvote/downvote buttons to mark this as the correct solution.

Comment: I see, and I thought it was working properly because, after the second click, it would add all the values to the same object. Thanks again! Good to know. I tested it out using your new adjustments and can confirm that it's working as I wanted. Can you explain the reasoning behind the last line `return newFavorite` I'm just wondering since it seems to work without it as well.

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain since you actually don't need `favorite` to be a hook (`useState`). Try using `const favoriteTemplate = {favoritable_type: 'Item', favoritor_type: 'User' }; const value =  { favoritor_id: props.current_user.id, favoritable_id: item.id }; createFavorite({...oldFavorite, ...value});` (inside of the `handleFavorite()` function, and you have to change and you have to remove setting the state in the `createFavorite()` function)

Comment: But besides that, when you use a `setHookName()` function, the return value of the function inside of it is the next value of the hook. With one-liner arrow functions, like `() => 5;` the 5 is an implied return. With `() => {...}` type functions, you have to explicitly tell it to return a certain value.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation. I really appreciate it and you were right about that last suggestion too. It worked without `favorite` being a hook. I just had to change the `oldFavorite` to `favoriteTemplate`. This was holding me back for more days than I'd like to admit.

Comment: `"I'm pretty new to hooks"` (from question). When we learn new things, sometimes we forget the simpler ways of doing things, in this case it was using a hook when variables work fine. It's perfected normal to think that you'd need hooks for this, but in this case you don't ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯