# why state updates on second time clicking in react js

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have a state which fills by name of empty form inputs. first time when you click on button it fills by some key but it is empty at all but in second time it fills by some key like "age" or other thing. Do anyone face with this kind of problem?

Comment: Hi, can you add the part of code that's responsible for this action?

Comment: Please share a code snippet of this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onClick function requires two clicks to update state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840853/onclick-function-requires-two-clicks-to-update-state)

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works:

```
<input value={age} onChange={(e)=>setAge(e.target.value)} />
```

or

```
setAge(()=>newValue);
```

if not, please share some code.